# when I try to get may data from db.json only shows "[ ]" on my main page,

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I was following the instructional video on YT in how to create a contact-pp in angular, I got stuck
in the part that we need to test if the data will display on the main page it only shows "[ ]".

this is some part of code.

*Icontact.ts*

```
export interface IContact {
    id?: string;
    name: string;
    email: string;
    photo: string;
    mobile: string;
    company: string;
    title: string;
    groupId: string;
}
```

*contact-manager.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IContact } from 'src/app/models/IContact';
import { ContactService } from 'src/app/services/contact.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact-manager',
  templateUrl: './contact-manager.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact-manager.component.css']
})
export class ContactManagerComponent implements OnInit {
    public loading:boolean = false;
    public contacts: IContact[] = [];
    public errorMessage:string | null = null;
    
   
  constructor(private contactService : ContactService)  {   
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loading = true;
    this.contactService.getAllContacts().subscribe((data:IContact[]) => {
      this.contacts = data;
      this.loading = false;
    },(error) => {
      this.errorMessage = error;
      this.loading = false;
      
    });
  }

}
```

*contact.service.ts*

```
import { HttpClientModule, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, catchError, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { IContact } from '../models/IContact';
import { IGroup } from '../models/IGroup';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ContactService {
  private serverUrl: string = 'http://localhost:9000'; //json-server
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { 

  }
  // get All Contacts
  public getAllContacts():Observable<IContact[]> {
    let dataUrl: string = '${this.serverUrl}/contacts';
    return this.httpClient.get<IContact[]>(dataUrl).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

   // GET Single Contact
   public getContacts(contactId: string): Observable<IContact>{
    let dataUrl: string = '${this.serverUrl}/contacts/${contactId}';
    return this.httpClient.get<IContact>(dataUrl).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
   }
 
   // Create a Contact
    public createContacts(contact : IContact):Observable<IContact>{
      let dataUrl: string = '${this.serverUrl}/contacts';
      return this.httpClient.post<IContact>(dataUrl, contact).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
    }

    // Update a Contact
    public updateContacts(contact : IContact, contactId: string):Observable<IContact>{
      let dataUrl: string = '${this.serverUrl}/contacts/${contactId}';
      return this.httpClient.put<IContact>(dataUrl, contact).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
    }

    // Delete a Contact
    public deleteContact(contactId: string):Observable<{}>{
      let dataUrl: string = '${this.serverUrl}/contacts/${contactId}';
      return this.httpClient.delete<{ }>(dataUrl).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
    }

    // Get All Groups
    public getAllGroups():Observable<IGroup[]> {
      let dataUrl: string = '${this.serverUrl}/groups';
      return this.httpClient.get<IGroup[]>(dataUrl).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
    }


    // Get Single Group
    public getGroup(contactId: IContact): Observable<IGroup>{
      let dataUrl: string = '${this.serverUrl}/groups/${contact.groupId}';
      return this.httpClient.get<IGroup>(dataUrl).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
     }

  // Error Handling 
  public handleError(error:HttpErrorResponse){
    let errorMessage:string = '';
     if(error.error instanceof ErrorEvent){
    //client Error
    errorMessage = 'Error : ${error.error.message}'
    }
    else{
      // server error
      errorMessage = 'Status : ${error.status} \n Message: ${error.message}' ;
    }
    return throwError (errorMessage);
    }
  }
```

when i tried to display the data on the main page to test if it will display it only shows "[ ]".

*component-manager.component.html*

```
div class="container mt-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <p class="h3 text-danger fw-bold">NG Contacts
                <a  class=" btn btn-danger btn-sm" routerLink="/contacts/add">
                  <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>  New</a>
            </p>
            <p class= "fst-italic">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Perspiciatis in unde qui, veritatis aspernatur iusto at incidunt harum, eveniet ipsam error quis! Iste, temporibus. Sit ut neque magnam unde laboriosam!</p>
        <form>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <input class="form-control" placeholder= "Search User" type="text">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <input class="btn btn-outline-dark" type="submit"  value="Search">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<pre>{{contacts | json}}</pre>
```

Comment: Is it normal that the route called by `this.httpClient.get` is wrapped with ' ' instead of ` ` ?

Comment: ohh my you are right

Comment: Does it solves your problem ?

Comment: yeah man thanks, now what i need is a pair of new glasses.